# How to access an object from PK of another object in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, api-design

The generic structure of the models is that there are teachers and devices, each device has a ForeignKey relationship with the teachers ID/PK.

I'm trying to create my API in such a way that when going to the detail view for a teacher, all of the associated devices are displayed.  I've overridden ***get_serializer_class()*** to specify which serializer to use at the appropriate time, but can't figure out how to correctly change the Queryset based on detail view or not.  Error posted below.

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `brand` on serializer `DeviceSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Teacher` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Teacher' object has no attribute 'brand'.

class TeacherViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Teacher.objects.order_by('campus','name')
    serializer_class = TeacherSerializer
    detail_serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            if hasattr(self, 'detail_serializer_class'):
                return self.detail_serializer_class
        return super(TeacherViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()

    def get_queryset(self, pk=None):
        if pk is not None:
            return Device.objects.filter(device__owner=self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return Teacher.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the desired output by adding a nested DeviceSerializer in my TeacherSerializer that parses the device object list.

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
devices = DeviceSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Teacher
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'campus', 'email', 'devices')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using DRF. If that is the case, just tweak `TeacherSerializer` to something like:

```
def TeachSearializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    devices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_devices(self, obj):
        return Devices.objects.filter(teacher=obj)
```

And that is it, everytime you use the serializer on a teacher object, their devices will be added on a field `devices`

Comment: So upon doing this I get Object of type Device is not JSON serializable, I am wondering if I need to serialize the Device object from within the TeacherSerializer